# How to optimize $ f(X)= \| X-M||_F^2 \\ $ with constraint $\sigma_{k+1}(X) \le a $

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(X)= \| X-M||_F^2 \\  \text{subject to} & \sigma_{k+1}(X) \le a
\end{array}$$

where $X\in R^{n \times m}$ is the  matrix;

$\sigma_{k+1}(X)$ is the $(k+1)^{th}$ largest sigular value of $X$ .

$a$ is just some constant e.g., a = 0.5; $M\in R^{n \times m}$ is the data matrix also constant.

It there any efficient algorithm (even rough approximation) to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: What are the assumptions for $M$? If $M$ is also symmetric and $\sigma_{k+1}(M) \le a$, then you would just set $X = M$.

Comment: Good point, I change a little bit about the $X$ and $M$.

Comment: A rough approximation is the following: $minimize \|X-M\|_F^2~ \text{subject to }  \|X-M\|_*\leq b$, where $\|X-M\|_*$ is the nuclear norm (sum of all singular values), and you should choose $b>a$ to account for the larger $k$ singular values. It's not exactly the same as what you want, but it will give you a similar sparsity patten in the singular values.

Comment: Well, the usual matrix calculus argument shows that the optimal objective function value is $\sum_{i=k+1}^{\min(m,n)}\left(\sigma_i(M)^2-\min(\sigma_i(M),a)\right)^2$. So, putting speed apart, the problem is at least solvable by performing singular value decomposition on $M$.

Comment: @user1551. Great, the problem can be solved by truncated the singular value of $M$. since SVD take expensive time. If any faster algorithm exist.